# CSV to RDF - Parse date to valid xsd:DateTime format

Tags: csv, datetime, xsd, sparql, rdf

I am using Tarql to convert some CSV data into rdf. The CSV contains a column of dates in the format "09/21/2017 12:15:00 AM".

I am using the below SPARQL where clause to transform the date in this column into a valid xsd:DateTime format.

```
SELECT ?date
WHERE {
    BIND ("([0-9][0-9]?)/([0-9][0-9]?)/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\\s*([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])\\s*([A-Z][A-Z])" AS ?DateRegex)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$1") AS ?month)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$2") AS ?day)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$3") AS ?year)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$4") AS ?hours)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$5") AS ?mins)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$6") AS ?sec)
    BIND (REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$7") AS ?clockPeriod)
    BIND (STRDT(CONCAT(?year, "-", ?month, "-", ?day, "T", IF(?clockPeriod = "PM", IF(?hours >= 1 && ?hours < 12, xsd:string(xsd:integer(?hours) + 12), ?hours), IF(?hours = 12, "00" , ?hours)), ":", ?mins, ":" , ?sec), xsd:dateTime) AS ?date)
}
```

This works fine when the hours do not require changing due to the 12-hr to 24-hr clock change, but the date isn't generated when the hours need to change. I'm assuming something is wrong in the last clause with the IFs.

Can anyone point out what the problem might be?

Comment: ok, I guess I found the issue: `?hours` is a string, but you compare it to integer numbers in the IF clause: `IF(?hours >= 1 && ?hours < 12` - it should be `BIND (xsd:integer(REPLACE(?Date, ?DateRegex, "$4")) AS ?hours)` to convert the hours to integer value and then you can do 
    `BIND (STRDT(CONCAT(?year, "-", ?month, "-", ?day, "T", IF(?clockPeriod = "PM", IF(?hours >= 1 && ?hours < 12, str(?hours + 12), str(?hours)), IF(?hours = 12, "00" , str(?hours))), ":", ?mins, ":" , ?sec), xsd:dateTime) AS ?date)`

Comment: @AKSW you are absolutely right, thank you!